# 日本語に違和感: ヘルプセンターの見出し: 質問中、回答中

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

それぞれ

「質問にあたって」

「回答にあたって」

はどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

下記の改正を実施しました。次回のビルドに適用。

「質問にあたって」

「回答にあたって」